# Building a future-proof webapp

Tags: linux, mysql, php

My app uses php, node.js, mysql and all the front-end trends. I am hosted on the Linode 4GB plan, 8 CPU (4x priority) and 8TB Transfer for the entire static website, api's etc, a cdn for static files and another smaller Linode server for my database. Yes, I have a different server for my database. I am using for both server Linux Debian 7.4.

Just in case, in my wildest dreams, my app goes viral:

- How do I know if my app can handle 20000 connections with all their sessions and users working with all these data simultaneously?
- Where should I start reading?
- What do other founders do?

I am **not** asking whether my current server is capable of handling all these, but if there is something I should do prior going live so that I should be ready in case of max-out, to deploy other servers and connect them probably with load balancers etc.

My app is purely on **PHP and MySQL** and just a tiny bit of node.js.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: There is no such thing as "future proof" in technology. Design it well, test it under load to determine what your pressure points will be (and how to scale them), and hope that your users don't do anything you didn't think of in testing (hint: ***They will***, so also be prepared to push fixes quickly.)

Answer (score 2):

> Where do I start on building a future-proof and scalable web app.

From [VIM](http://www.vim.org/).

> How do I know if my app can handle 2000 connections with all their sessions and users working with all these data simultaneously?

[Test it, silly](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)!

> Where should I start reading?

Everything you can on scalability.

> What do other founders do?

They hire [people with experience that know what they're doing](http://blog.discourse.org/2013/02/the-discourse-team/).